# Try-catch ignoring the assignment of a variable when executing an SQL query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oop

This piece of code uses an SQL query to return how many entries there are in a certain table.

```
public int countAmountOfEntries() {
    int amount;
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Connection.JDBC_URL); 
            PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table")) {
        try (ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                amount = rs.getInt("COUNT(*)");
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    return amount;
}
```

This should return any int other than `0`. Initialising the variable to `0` will result in a `NullPointerException` being thrown as I'm using the return value of this to set the length of an array. Using the same code in another class returns the int it should return. I've tried using an alias for the `COUNT(*)` but to no avail.

Running the query directly into MySQL returns the int as well. I've tried removing the nested try (it was pretty much obsolete since I know it won't throw an exception if no one messes with my DB).

Comment: _"obsolete since I know it won't throw an exception"_ -- you don't, which is why it's NEVER "obsolete".

Comment: Badly worded on my part. Nothing in the program alters that table, it is only read. I gave specific instructions to the 3 other people with access to that database to not alter anything in that table and I regularly check it. I see your point though, if someone were to alter it, it would give problems. I did it mainly to see if that would do anything, which it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you register the JDBC driver before using it?

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Is it required to provide an username/password upon connecting?

```
DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

Did you create a `Connection` class yourself which overwrites the `Connection` class returned upon opening the connection. The reason I ask this is because you retrieve the URL to connect to using `Connection.JDBC_URL` which is (as far as I know) not in the `Connection` class.

Is there already a connection opened and your database only allows 1 open connection?

**Note:** do not forget to close the resultset, statement, and connection before returning:

```
rs.close();
query.close();
conn.close();
```

Besides that, restructure your function because a try without catch does not help at all.

Comment: I've removed the inner `try`. The `Connection` class should be completely fine as it worked fine using different methods. As I said, the weirdest thing about it is that it does work when used in a different class. That means the problem lies within the class itself, but weirdly enough, everything else works fine.

Comment: Please try to add the line `Class.forName` at the top of this function once. Because the class loader's cache could be garbage collected in the mean time. Or maybe this code is executed before the `Class.forName` is even executed once?

Comment: The try block is already closing the resultset, statement, and connection. It shouldn't be removed.

Comment: I made the Connection class myself, with the attribute `public static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql:/hostname?user=username&password=mypassword"`. It worked fine before, only after adding a method did the other methods stop working. The method added is used in the others to provide an int for the length of an array.  I'll try running the methods without that last one.

Answer (score 0):

This looks really weird:

```
amount = rs.getInt("COUNT(*)");
```

Try this instead

```
amount = rs.getInt(1);
```

Comment: I've tried using both the index and an alias, doesn't seem to work.